# CORS blocking file uploads in Expressjs

Tags: express, cors

i've tried adding headers manually and used express cors.

i've read this : https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

followed the instruction, and all is good, every request [GET, PUT, POST,DELETE,PATCH] i send pass through, but. if i tried to upload files to the server CORS blocked me.

the message :

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.example.xyz/api/post' from origin 'https://app.example.xyz' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

but the CORS BLock is gone if i removed anything that handle moving the files from the request body.

i've tried multr , express-fileupload, and moving the image manually with node fs, cors always blocks me.
please help.

how do i upload file with express ? is this my server faults ? it works on locally.

Comment: All questions about code here on stackoverflow should show the relevant portions of your actual code.  That allows us to help you quicker, more accurately and more specifically without having to guess what you are or aren't doing.  Questions about code should include that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely because there are two kinds of CORs requests, "simple requests" and "pre-flighted" requests.  You don't show your code (which you should), but your symptoms sounds like you're handling [simple requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests) just fine, but your upload is triggering a [pre-flighted request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests) and you don't have CORS approval code for pre-flighted requests.

A pre-flighted request sends an OPTIONS request before it sends the actual request and asks for permission and your server needs to properly respond to the OPTIONS request with the CORS headers to allow the browser to send the pre-flighted request.

You can see for sure what's happening by opening up the Chrome debugger and going to the network tab and seeing exactly what the browser sends to your server during this request.

If this explanation isn't enough for you to figure out how to solve your problem, then please show the EXACT screenshot from the network tab of your browser's attempt to send that request AND show the relevant portions of your server code, both your CORs middleware and the target request handler.